# Using pandas to plot barplots with error bars

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I'm trying to generate bar plots from a DataFrame like this:

```
            Pre    Post
 Measure1   0.4    1.9
```

These values are median values I calculated from elsewhere, and I have also their variance and standard deviation (and standard error, too). I would like to plot the results as a bar plot with the proper error bars, but specifying more than one error value to `yerr` yields an exception:

```
# Data is a DataFrame instance
fig = data.plot(kind="bar", yerr=[0.1, 0.3])

[...]
ValueError: In safezip, len(args[0])=1 but len(args[1])=2
```

If I specify a single value (incorrect) all is fine. How can I actually give each column its correct error bar?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What is your data shape?

For an n-by-1 data vector, you need a n-by-2 error vector (positive error and negative error):

```python
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df2 = pd.DataFrame([0.4, 1.9])
df2.plot(kind='bar', yerr=[[0.1, 3.0], [3.0, 0.1]])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The shape is 1 row and 2 columns. I tried the above with my data and it still errors out.

Comment: Can you just flatten your matrix into a vector like above ? Anyway, I've looked deeper into pandas.DataFrame.plot and I didn't find a way to plot errors bars for matrix datas. You may have to fall back on mathplotlib : [MatplotlibBarPlots](http://www.duke.edu/~ccc14/pcfb/numpympl/MatplotlibBarPlots.html)

Comment: I've had better luck by transposing the matrix: like that it works.

Comment: I'll note using Pandas v1 I could pass `yerr` into `plot` but I had to use `.values` to drop the index (even thought the index matched what was being plotted). Passing in a `(2, N)` array worked just fine.

Comment: I am confused, what are the values `[3.0, 0.1]` for? The errorbar is just determined by `[0.1, 3.0]`

Answer (score 3):

## if lucasg's answer does not work

For whatever reason, the accepted answer did not work properly for me (compare my comment there). I am using the following versions

**Versions:** Python 3.7.6 (anaconda), mpl: 3.1.3, pd: 1.0.1, np: 1.18.1

What worked, however is a modification of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13130703/7128154).
That questions discussion points also in the direction that, there might be some problems with different versions and asymmetric error bar plotting.

**Code**
Plots asymmetric errorbars from min to max around the mean of a dataframe column.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print('Versions, mpl: {:}, pd: {:}, np: {:}'.format(mpl.__version__, pd.__version__, np.__version__))

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['a'] = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3]
df['b'] = [0.5, 0.5, 2, 3, 4]
print(df)

plt.bar(np.arange(df.shape[1]), df.mean(), yerr=[df.mean()-df.min(), df.max()-df.mean()], capsize=6)
plt.grid()

plt.show()
```

[image]