# Plotting asymmetrical error bars with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, errorbar

I'm currently using Python 3.4, Pandas 0.20.3 and Matplotlib 2.1.0. A similar question was asked at [matplotlib bar with asymmetrical error bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130703/matplotlib-bar-with-asymmetrical-error-bars) using earlier versions of Pandas and Matplotlib but, in that case, the code produced errors whereas, in my case, the code produces the wrong graph.

Basically, I have a Pandas dataframe consisting of several columns of data and an index of named values. I want to plot one of the columns as a bar chart and include asymmetrical error bars. I have defined the lower and upper error bars as a list of two lists, the first representing the lower error bars and the second representing the upper error bars. However, when I plot a bar chart, the error bars are symmetrical based on the first list; the second list only comes into play if I plot a bar chart of both columns.

The code I am using can be summarised as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

myDF = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[4,5,6,7],'col2':[6,5,4,5]},index=['A','B','C','D'])
print(myDF)

err = [[0.5,0.5,2,2],[2,2,3,3]]

ax = myDF.loc[:,['col1']].plot(kind = 'bar',yerr = err)
```

which gives:

```
   col1  col2
A     4     6
B     5     5
C     6     4
D     7     5
```

...and produces the following plot:

[image]

I assume I'm missing something obvious but I can't put my finger on the mistake; can somebody please enlighten me?

Comment: The question you linked to does not include `pandas`. I can confirm that using pure `matplotlib` this _does_ work. Could be a bug in `pandas`?

Comment: Thanks for confirming that it works in pure matplotlib. Maybe that's the way to go and leave a bug report on the pandas site.

Comment: I don't know much about the interaction of pandas and matplotlib, maybe someone who knows more than me can give a more concrete answer or say for sure if this is a bug