# Plotting asymmetric error bars for a single point using errorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib

Goal: To plot asymmetric x error bars for a single point using errorbar. I want to display the inter quartile range (IQR) for a data set.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = 1.0
data = np.random.rand(100)

median = np.median(data)
upper_quartile = np.percentile(data, 75)
lower_quartile = np.percentile(data, 25)
IQR = upper_quartile - lower_quartile

plt.errorbar(median, y, xerr=[lower_quartile ,upper_quartile], fmt='k--')

plt.savefig('IQR.eps')
plt.show()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "IQR.py", line 15, in <module>
    plt.errorbar(median, y, xerr=[0.5,0.75], fmt='k--')
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2251, in errorbar
    ret = ax.errorbar(x, y, yerr, xerr, fmt, ecolor, elinewidth, capsize, barsabove, lolims, uplims, xlolims, xuplims, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 5327, in errorbar
    in cbook.safezip(x,xerr)]
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/cbook.py", line 1294, in safezip
    raise ValueError(_safezip_msg % (Nx, i+1, len(arg)))
ValueError: In safezip, len(args[0])=1 but len(args[1])=2
```

My issue is that I am unable to create asymmetric error bars for a single point, where the point will represent the mean and the upper and lower limits of the error bars will be the upper and lower quartile.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Upper/lower limits with matplotlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621643/upper-lower-limits-with-matplotlib)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I typically use `vlines` or `hlines` for this (I think the caps are just distracting):

```
 plt.hlines( y, median-lower_quartile, median+upper_quartile)
 plt.plot(median, y, 'o')
```

[image: Simple plot]

If you still want to use `errorbar`, you can try

```
plt.errorbar(median, y, xerr=np.array([[lower_quartile ,upper_quartile]]).T, 
        fmt='ko')
```

[image: with errorbar]

Note that I don't really know how you define your quartiles here, so you may need to make sure you get the right numbers in!!!

Comment: Thanks @Jose! This is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Also many thanks to @Jose: I was killing myself trying to map an errorplot to a Seaborn FacetGrid and pass in a 2xN matrix. This is so much better

Answer (score 2):

Make sure xerr gets a list of lists. If it's only one list, it'll assume it contains symmetrical error bars for two Y's. But there's only one Y, which is why you get the error.

Also your errorbars are wrong. Change the errorbar call to

`plt.errorbar(median, y, xerr=[[median-lower_quartile ,upper_quartile-median]], fmt='k--')`

Answer (score -1):

The two arguments you're passing to safezip are of different sizes. The stacktrace you posted says so right here:

```
ValueError: In safezip, len(args[0])=1 but len(args[1])=2
```

What that's saying is argument one's length is 1 but argument two's length is 2, so zip can't actually combine those two lists.

Comment: Thank you. Any suggestions on how to plot asymmetric error bars for a single point?